What is the proper way to deal with the resource path?
I'm working with Python and multiple of my GUI classes require some images.
Is it okay to simply add the resource path via a constant and import it everywhere?
The other approach I was considering was to make setters for each of them and use them while initializing the app. But I feel like this creates unnecessary complexity.
Are these valid, are there other approaches?

Competent implementations of resource management in Python:
Constants: Best for small projects or when data paths are unlikely to change.
Setters: Useful when paths need to be customized at runtime.
Configuration files: Suitable for large projects with lots of data, providing easy management.
# config.yaml
image_path: "path/to/image.png"

# config.py
import yaml

def load_config():
    with open("config.yaml", "r") as file:
        return yaml.safe_load(file)

config = load_config()

# gui_class.py
from config import config
from PIL import Image

class MyGUIClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_path = config['image_path']
        self.load_image(self.image_path)
    
    def load_image(self, path):
        self.image = Image.open(path)

Resource Management Class: Best for encapsulating data logic and providing reuse.
class ResourceManager:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
    
    def get_image(self, image_name):
        return Image.open(self.config[image_name])

Сonclusion:
It's important to structure your code in a way that makes resource paths easy to update and maintain.
Choose the approach that best fits the size, complexity, and flexibility of your project. For many applications, the best variant may be to start with constants or a configuration file and move to a more complex solution as needed.
